# How is my ring buffer adding an additional element?

Tags: c, linux, buffer

I have a ring buffer example code that I'm practicing and for some odd reason, it adds an extra element with no apparent reason.
The behavior I am coding is that it drops incoming data if buffer is full.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    void *buf;
    ssize_t ri; //read index
    ssize_t wi; //write index
    ssize_t capacity; // total size of buffer in bytes
    size_t max_count;
    size_t count;
    ssize_t sz; // size of individual elements in bytes
    bool full;
} r_buffer_t;

r_buffer_t* ring_buffer_init(unsigned int count, ssize_t dsize) {
    r_buffer_t *buffer = malloc(sizeof(r_buffer_t));
    if(buffer != NULL){
        buffer->buf =  malloc(count * sizeof(dsize));
        if(buffer->buf != NULL) {
            buffer->max_count = count;
            buffer->sz = dsize;
            buffer->count = 0;
            buffer->ri = 0;
            buffer->wi = 0;
            buffer->capacity = count * dsize;
            buffer->full = false;
            return buffer;
        }
        free(buffer);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int put_item(r_buffer_t *buffer, void *data) {
    assert(buffer && data); // exception catch on stderr;
    if(!buffer->full) {
        printf("\nw-memcpy");
        memcpy((buffer->buf + (buffer->wi * buffer->sz)), data, sizeof(buffer->sz));
        printf("\n\t\tret\tdata\tcount\tfull\twi");
        //printf("\n-------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("\nAdding data :\t%d\t%d\t%ld\t%d\t%ld", 0, *((int*)data), buffer->count, buffer->full, buffer->wi);
        buffer->count++;
        buffer->wi++;
        buffer->wi %= buffer->max_count;
        //if((buffer->wi == buffer->ri) && (buffer->count >= (buffer->max_count))) {
        if(buffer->count >= buffer->max_count) {
            printf("\n>>>Full for count = %ld, buffer-full = %d, index ri = %ld, wi=%ld",
                buffer->count, buffer->full, buffer->ri, buffer->wi);
            buffer->full = true;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\n>>>Dropping data. Buffer Full for count = %ld, buffer-full = %d, index ri = %ld, wi=%ld",
                buffer->count, buffer->full, buffer->ri, buffer->wi);
    //printf("\n%d\t%d\t%ld\t%d", -1, *((int *)data), buffer->count, buffer->full);
    return -1;
}

int get_item(r_buffer_t *buffer, void *data) {
    assert(buffer && data);
    if(buffer->count > 0) {
        printf("r-memcpy");
        memcpy(data, (buffer->buf + (buffer->ri * buffer->sz)), buffer->sz);
        memset((buffer->buf + (buffer->ri * buffer->sz)), 0, buffer->sz);
        //printf("\n%d\t%d\t%ld\t%d\t%ld", 0, *((int*)data), buffer->count, buffer->full, buffer->ri);
        buffer->count--;
        buffer->ri++;
        buffer->ri %= buffer->max_count;
        buffer->full = (buffer->count >= buffer->max_count);
        return 0;
    }
    //printf("\n%d\t%d\t%ld\t%d\t%ld", -1, *((int*)data), buffer->count, buffer->full, buffer->ri);
    return -1;
}
void print_buffer(r_buffer_t *buffer) {
    int i = 0;
    printf("\n*************Buffer***********\n");
    printf("\ncount = %ld, full = %d, ri = %ld, wi = %ld",
            buffer->count, buffer->full, buffer->ri, buffer->wi);
    printf("\n\t");
    for(i =0; i < buffer->max_count; i++){
        if(buffer->ri == i)
            printf("R  ");
        else
            printf("   ");
    }
    printf("\n\t");
    for(i =0; i < buffer->max_count; i++)
        printf("%d |", *(int *)(buffer->buf + i * buffer->sz));
    printf("\n\t");
    for(i =0; i < buffer->max_count; i++){
        if(buffer->wi == i)
            printf("W  ");
        else
            printf("   ");
    }
    printf("\n*********************************\n");
}
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int d1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int rd = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    r_buffer_t *buf = ring_buffer_init(5, sizeof(unsigned int));
    print_buffer(buf);
    printf("\nAdding 4 items to buffer");
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
        printf("\nCalling put for %d", d1[i]);
        ret = put_item(buf, (void *)&d1[i]);
    }
    print_buffer(buf);
    printf("\nRemoving and printing 2");
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        get_item(buf, &rd);
    }
    print_buffer(buf);
    printf("\nAdding 4 more items to buffer");
    for(i = 4; i < 9; i++) { 
        ret = put_item(buf, &d1[i]);
    }
    print_buffer(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

The output makes no sense:

```
*************Buffer***********

count = 0, full = 0, ri = 0, wi = 0
        R              
        0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |
        W              
*********************************

Adding 4 items to buffer
Calling put for 1
w-memcpy
                ret     data    count   full    wi
Adding data :   0       1       0       0       0
Calling put for 2
w-memcpy
                ret     data    count   full    wi
Adding data :   0       2       1       0       1
Calling put for 3
w-memcpy
                ret     data    count   full    wi
Adding data :   0       3       2       0       2
Calling put for 4
w-memcpy
                ret     data    count   full    wi
Adding data :   0       4       3       0       3
*************Buffer***********

count = 4, full = 0, ri = 0, wi = 4
        R              
        1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |
                    W  
*********************************
```

How is there an extra '5' in the buffer ?

Comment: I can't *exactly* reproduce your error because I don't have a compiler (like GCC) that supports arithmetic on a `void*` pointer. However, changing that to a `char*` and then fixing the mismatch issues in your various `printf` calls seems to stop your problem. ...

Comment: ... try replacing your `%ld` specifiers with `%zd` (for the `ssize_t` variables) to remove the **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: `buffer->buf + (buffer->wi * buffer->sz)` is an invalid computation as `buffer->buf` is a `void *`.  Use a defined address computation.

Comment: @preetam, `buffer->buf =  malloc(count * sizeof(dsize));` is very suspicious.  Did you want `buffer->buf =  malloc(count * dsize);`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, dsize is the size of element and count is number of elements. It is as per design.

Comment: @preetam "`dsize` is the size of element" --> OK, lets us say `count = 42`, the size of the element is 1024, size is is saved in `unsigned dsize = 1024` and on your system, an `unsigned` takes 4 bytes.  Then code is `buffer->buf =  malloc(42 * 4);` when I think you want `42 * 1024`.  Perhaps a calling code example would help?  Looks like a problem like `sizeof(buffer->sz)`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, Thanks for the catch. The sizeof was leftover from another implementation I tried. It got me at both malloc and in memcpy. Surprisingly, I had properly updated memcpy in get_item function. The only reason this was working is because I was using ints and sizes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
memcpy((buffer->buf + (buffer->wi * buffer->sz)), data, sizeof(buffer->sz));
```

The above line in `put_item()` would copy a number of `sizeof(buffer->sz)` bytes from `data` to `(buffer->buf + (buffer->wi * buffer->sz))`.

The `sizeof(buffer->sz)` equals to `sizeof(ssize_t)` for the type of `buffer->sz` is `ssize_t` in type `r_buffer_t`.

In many system, `ssize_t` would be `signed long` while `size_t` would be `unsigned long`, and they would be double the `sizeof(int)` bytes in general. It is possible that the above code line actually copy double the `sizeof(int)` bytes from the source to destination, then at the fourth call to `put_item()` the fifth element in array `d1[]` would always be copied into the ring buffer.

You might want to change it as the following line.

```
memcpy((buffer->buf + (buffer->wi * buffer->sz)), data, buffer->sz);
```

Comment: I don't know how I ended up putting a `sizeof(buffer-sz)` instead of simply `buffer->sz`. I even missed looking at at. Thanks  a lot.